# Geometry vs geography for line-to-polygon intersection

Tags: postgis, geometry, postgis-2.0, intersection

I have two <s>WGS84</s> NAD83 shapefiles, one polygonal, the other containing lines:

```
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1294
Extent: (-79.761059, 44.991143) - (-57.105486, 62.582865)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 427227
Extent: (-79.882212, 44.929534) - (-55.834430, 62.427856)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

which I export to PostGIS 2 using the `-G` flag, to obtain geographies:

```
$ shp2pgsql -G -I -s 4326 polygons | psql ...
$ shp2pgsql -G -I -s 4326 lines | psql ...
```

However when I perform a query to obtain their intersection:

```
select * from polygons p, lines l
where p.geog && l.geog 
and st_intersects(p.geog, l.geog)
```

it runs for a very, very long time, and doesn't yield the same results as the one performed **over the equivalent tables, but with geometries instead** (i.e. `shp2pgsql` without the `-G` flag), which runs very rapidly. According to the docs, `st_intersects` should play well with both types, so why this difference?

Comment: Can you add the extent of the two shapefiles?

Comment: They both span the entire Quebec province, I updated my question with their infos.

Comment: Woups, I just realized that I assumed my shapefiles to be WGS84, whereas they seem to be NAD83! I guess that explains my problem, as geographies work only with the latter, right? Shouldn't both systems be more or less equivalent though?

Answer (score 2):

The results may [very legitimately be different](http://boundlessgeo.com/2012/04/the-earth-is-not-flat-volume-2/).

Interpretations on a plane are not the same as interpretations on a sphere, and that's what you're seeing when you compare geometry to geography calculations.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html):

> For geography, this function has a distance tolerance of about 0.00001
>   meters and uses the sphere rather than spheroid calculation.

Unless the CRS you are using for your geometries also uses a sphere, the result will always be different.

Answer (score 1):

The [Postgis documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) notes that SRID 4326 is mandatory for geography, and calculations will take longer because they are done on a sphere instead of a plane as would be done for projected coordinates.