# What is the metric of the radius PostGIS query?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am trying to make a query (using raw query in sequelize orm for a PostgreSQL with PostGIS database) for a radius of a certain 'maxDistance' radius (preferably in meters):

```
const maxDistance = 100000000

const lat = 4.307662331310191
const lon = 52.09468958820517
const sequelize = hook.app.get('sequelizeClient')

return sequelize.query(`SELECT "id", "created_at", "wkb_geometry", ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${parseFloat(lat)}, ${parseFloat(lon)}), 3857), "wkb_geometry") AS distance FROM "points" WHERE ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${parseFloat(lat)}, ${parseFloat(lon)}), 3857), "wkb_geometry") < ${maxDistance}`)
```

When I create another point, i.e.: `const HOME_LONLAT = [4.295980701608052, 52.09069818826458]` in the database and run the query I get a result with a distance of `0.012344705180102` however the actual distance of these two geopoints is approx 930 meters. What am I doing wrong or how should I convert the distance to get the distance in meters?

EDIT:
When I alter the query into:

```
'SELECT "id", "created_at", "wkb_geometry", ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText(\'SRID=3857;POINT(4.307662331310191 52.09468958820517)\'), "wkb_geometry") AS distance FROM "points" WHERE ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText(\'SRID=3857;POINT(4.307662331310191 52.09468958820517)\'), "wkb_geometry") < 100000000'
```

I get this error:

```
error: Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography
```

EDIT2:
In PostGIS I have 3857 CRS:

```
SELECT ST_SRID("wkb_geometry") FROM points;
 st_srid 
---------
    3857
```

Comment: cast geometry to geography > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223845/using-geometry-in-postgis

Comment: on a side note you build the points using lat-long, but it should be long-lat instead, and these coordinates are not in 3857 but likely in 4326

Comment: Side note: EPSG:3857 is rather useless for distance and area calculations. Take the geography route or if you work locally use some projected system with less distortion.

Comment: @JGH Uh.., what makes you think the coords are in 4326 ?

Comment: Because your coordinates look like they are in degrees (0;0 in 3857 is in the ocean), and 4326 is a very popular CRS. Of course it is only a guess and you may want to double check your source CRS

Comment: @JGH I think I need 3857 as it is what mapbox-gl.js uses and that is what I use. The coords are in The Hague of The Netherlands..., pretty sure it is 3857...

Comment: While you may be visualizing this in EPSG:3857, the coordinate data looks geodetic. They are most likely EPSG:4326.

Comment: The unit of geometry data type calculations is always the units of the SRID. If meters then meters; if degrees, then Cartesian degrees (which are useless). Equally useless for measurement purposes is any Web Mercator projection (e.g. 3857), the values of which in your area of interest are spectacularly inaccurate.

Comment: @Vince Actually I could live with a slightly lesser accuracy for my use-case, however 0.012344705180102 * 111 km/degree = 1370 meters, which for an actual distance of 930 meters is an overstatement of 47%. I read that you get 10% deviations..., so my outcome can not be degrees I think.

Comment: I am confused. I've read and try to understand the whole 3857 vs 4326 conundrum, but don't. Anyway I store in my postgis model using ` wkb_geometry: {
      type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT', 3857),
      field: 'wkb_geometry',
      allowNull: true
    }` which makes me think I have my points in 3857 CRS?! I was also under the impression that when I refer to locations in The Netherlands with 4326 my coords will be something like (x) 479535 and (y) 6817272 and using 3857 more like (lat) 52 and (lon) 4, so I am kind of surprised that several of you now suggest that my data 'is 4326'...?

Comment: Anyway, how do I proceed to get good measurements? Can I convert somehow, or am I stuck?

Comment: You have a mistake to undo. Encoding an SRID of Web Mercator on WGS84 data prevents any useful operations. You must encode what *is* before using automated conversion techniques. If you want to store data in 3857 you must transform it from 4326, at which point distance operations need to be performed by transforming back to 4326 then casting to geography. If you instead knowingly store the data in WGS84 (with the correct SRID), then distance operations are available as a cast, but mapping in 3857 requires a transform. As it stands, you're lying to the software, so it can't give an answer.

Comment: I am getting there... Looks like storing in srid 4326 is the way to go and 'what everyone is doing'.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: "(lat) 52 and (lon) 4" are coords in 4326 (degrees),  "(x) 479535 and (y) 6817272" are in 3857 (meters).

Comment: @JGH When I query my postgis database with ST_SRID it gives srid 3857 and when I query it with ST_ASTEXT it gives POINT(4.29598070160805 52.0906981882646). So please explain why "(lat) 52 and (lon) 4" are in 4326, as it (still) looks like 3857 to me...

Comment: -1.  You write degrees in a column that expect meters, so your point is 52 meters away from 0;0, in the ocean near the equator

Comment: The -1 is a downvote for my ignorance?! Anyway, what makes this confusing for me is that in my mapbox-gl.js the points show exactly where they belong, so probably I accidently 'correct' things within my mapserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [seems a common practice is to store](http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/4326-vs-3857) in SRID 4326 (which enables accurate distance calculations etc.) and use SRID 3857 for mapping (to 2D), so my storage in SRID 3857 is 'working against me'.

After storing in SRID 4326 and making my mapserver serve the conversion to SRID 3857, I could alter my query into:

```
return sequelize.query(`SELECT "id", "created_at", "wkb_geometry", ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${parseFloat(lon)}, ${parseFloat(lat)}), 4326), "wkb_geometry") AS distance FROM "points" WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${parseFloat(lon)}, ${parseFloat(lat)}), 4326), "wkb_geometry") < ${maxDistance}`)
```

It gives the distance in meters now and is accurate.

BTW: The exact answer to the original question can not be given as I was storing srid 4326 data in srid 3857 postgis column which results in an undetermined radius calculation.